# How do I pass a parameter from component to a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, controller, parameters

Can I pass a email value from a visualforce component to a Visualforce page?
I have used components for reusing Company's logo and few images...

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Logo}"> </apex:image>
</apex:component>
```

Is it possible to pass variable to a visualforce page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass in the controller of your visualforce page.  This means you'll need either a custom controller or an extension.  When you pass in the controller, you can then call getters or setters on the controller given they are publicly accessible.

For example:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="ctrl" description="My controller" type="MyControllerClassName" required="true"/>
    <apex:image value="{!URLFOR(ctrl.ImageUrlGetter)}"> </apex:image>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 12):

There is an extensive blog post on the Developerforce website [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication) regarding this matter to help you out.

As a summary - you should pass in the controller of your page as an apex attribute of your component (just as James mentions). You will have your component look like

```
<apex:component controller="MyComponentController" >
    <apex:attribute name="pageController" type="PageControllerBase" assignTo="{!pageController}" required="true" description="The controller for the page." />
</apex:component>
```

Which on your page you will use as

```
<c:myComponent pageController="{!pageCont}" />
```

This will then assign the page controller returned in the "getPageCont" method on your page controller to the "pageController" parameter/property in your component. A method in your page's controller to return itself is needed for the "getPageCont" call.

```
public PageControllerBase getPageCont()
{
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Can you summarise here?

Comment: Done :-) Uses snippets from the link.

Comment: What is pageCont in the component?

Comment: Should be a bit clearer now hopefully - you are assigning the pageControllerBase instance used as the controller of your page to the pageController parameter in the component using an intermediary getPageCont method.

Comment: This is impossible to maintain, the view state of the page will be duplicated with each injection.

Answer (score 8):

If you feel passing the entire controller of your visualforce page is a bit too heavy-weighted, or if you need a generic component that can be reused across pages, you can also use a dedicated class to carry the data that you need to transport back and forth between page and component.

I.e. create a 'data' class like this:

```
public with sharing class ComponentData {
    public String theInput {get;set;}
    public String theOutput {get;set;}
}
```

In your page controller, instantiate the class:

```
public ComponentData theData {get;set;}
```

On your component, use the class as an attribute:

```
<apex:component controller="CompController">
<apex:attribute type="ComponentData" name="compData" required="true" description="The data going in and out" assignTo="{!cData}"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="banManagerPanel">
    <apex:inputText value="{!cData.input}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateData}"/>
    </apex:inputText>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

On the component controller you can perform whatever logic that needs to be done:

```
public with sharing class ComponentController {
public ComponentData cData {get;set;}
public void updateData(){
    cData.theOutput = cData.theInput + ' with something extra';
}
}
```

And finally, on the VF page pass the instantiated data-class to the component:

```
<c:theComponent compData="{!theData}"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!theData.theOutput}" />
```

The theData on the VF page will get the updated value that was modified by the component controller, after the button inside the component is pressed.

Comment: I have a button on the page and not on the Component. I mean that I want to capture Component data as well as page data and save it. I'm not able to figure out how to do this...

Comment: Hi @helpSFDC, please post a new question on stackexchange, possibly referring this one and we will try helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @guy ! Thats a great way to work with components.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the `apex:attribute`'s type attribute doesn't recognize internal classes (which I would normally use for a small class that is essentially a struct), but this is still a much cleaner model than passing around controller refs.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go.. It closely resembles using the  DTO Pattern. Rather than pass the reference to the whole parent page's controller .

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Create a div on page and assign value to that div from component after execution of component and its controller. Fetch value from that div mentioned in the page.

Let me know if you need example.

Example :-

Here, Assign value to the div with id --> "finalQueryId". You can access this div value on page.

```
<c:FilterComponent objectName="Contact" fieldsSeparatedByComma="Id,Name,Email" 
                                                                    divId="finalQueryId"/>

<div id="finalQueryId" style="display:none"/>
```

Comment: Interesting! Can you show the code for assigning the value to the div from component after execution of component and its controller?

Comment: If the component is referred in the page then you can assign the value to that div directly from component. Lemme add a snippet

Comment: ------- Page code ------

<apex:page>
 
 <c:component/>
 
 <div id="finalDivId"/>
 
</apex:page>

------- Component code ------
<apex:component>
 <script>
  $('#finalDivId').html('Post value you want to -->' + {!controllerVariable});
 </script>
</apex:component>

Comment: has anyone tried the above approach? it does not work for me unless it needs to add more logic to it.